# FORM VALIDATION ERROR: Anytime I click on the submit button, I get appended error result on the errorDiv

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have created a form and a script to check if user inputs the required field. However, each time I press the submit button, I get an appended list of errors I created for the validation.

```
var error = "";
var subject = $("#subject").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
var content = $("#content").val();
var errorDiv = $("#errorText"); 

//option A
$("form").submit(function(e){

    if (email == ""){
      error += "Please enter a valid email <br>";
    }

    if (subject == ""){
      error += "<p>The Subject field is required <br>";
    }


    if(content == ""){
      error+= "Please enter details <br>"
    }

    if(error != ""){
      errorDiv.html('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><p>There were error(s) in your form:</p>' + error + '</div>');
      return false;
    }
    else{
      return true;
    }

});
```

Here is an image of what I'm experiencing 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1YoB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't initialized `error`. Since you didn't declare it as a local variable, it's a global variable, so it keeps holding the value from the previous validation.

And the variables that contain the input field values also need to be set in the function. Otherwise, they just contain the values from when the page was loaded, not when the user submits the form.

```js
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  var error = "";
  var subject = $("#subject").val();
  var email = $("#email").val();
  var content = $("#content").val();

  if (email == "") {
    error += "Please enter a valid email <br>";
  }

  if (subject == "") {
    error += "<p>The Subject field is required <br>";
  }

  if (content == "") {
    error += "Please enter details <br>"
  }

  if (error != "") {
    errorDiv.html('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><p>There were error(s) in your form:</p>' + error + '</div>');
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }

});
```

Comment: Hi @barmar I have updated the code. Did you see the image I just attached?

Comment: All the other variables need to be inside the function, too.

Comment: Thanks. Works now